# SharePoint Custom Timer Job

Tags: sharepoint-server, custom-timer-job

I have a requirement to create a multiple timer job within a single feature.

I have created the SharePoint Timer Job with the reference of this site http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/634208/Create-and-Deploy-Custom-Timer-Job-Definition-in-S.

I can able to send an email with the first timer job that I have created. But I want to create another timer job with in the same feature itself.For that I have created another timer job it is working fine. But the execute method is not working for sending the mail for the second job.

Please help me on this.

Thanks In Advance

Saranya

Comment: Have you resolved your problem? Or my answer is correct for your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it up to my knowledge. This is one of the HUGE drawbacks to SharePoint in my opinion.

Any time you make deployments for example, You have to schedule those because you know the app pool is going to recycle.